# Multiple static IP adresses for Xen

Tags: networking, xen, sles

I'm trying to set up Xen on SLES11. The configuration I want is that each of the virtual machines shall have it's own static IP address externally to our LAN and thus can be accessed directly via a specific IP.

```
LAN - eth0(IP: 1.2.3.4)    -   ??  - vm1 (IP: 1.2.3.5)
                                   - vm2 IP: (1.2.3.6)
                                   - vm3 IP: (1.2.3.7)
                                   - ...
```

So that I can access vm1 from outside the host machine directly with ip 1.2.3.5.
My question is, how do I set this up? What should I have instead of '??' in the picture? I have searched on the net but can't find anything about using multiple static addresses in this way.

And yes I am a bit new to more complex network configurations.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to set up Xen in bridge mode. You can do that in the /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp by disabling

> (network-script network-dummy)

and enabling

> (network-script network-bridge)
>
> (vif-script vif-bridge)

After you have a bridge set up, all you have to do is put the public IPs on your domU's and that's it.

> ifconfig ethy x.x.x.x/netmask

You can also create your bridge by hand which works perfectly fine also and tends to be more upgrade-proof.

Comment: Ah, so much easier than I thought :) Thank's for the answer!

Comment: Don't hesitate to mark my answer :-)